# Create a segue to a different NavigationController

Tags: xcode, swift

I have an app that has two navigation controllers. I'm trying to create the segue shown in the red arrow below: Pressing the "+" button should take you to a specific view controller of another NavigationController.

[image]

I've been able to successfully go to this view controller but it doesn't have any navigation properties (Pressing "Back" doesn't do anything).

How do I jump to a view controller in a different navigation controller but still retain navigation properties?

Answer (score 0):

I will say you want to move from controller A to controller B for reference.

Each `UINavigationController` instance has a `viewControllers` array that stores the controllers in the navigation stack.

In your case, the first navigation controller has 2 view controllers in the navigation stack, the same thing for the second navigation controller.

If you press back in the view controller B, it should pop to one of the view controllers in the `UINavigationController` stack to which B belongs. Since controller A et B don't belong to the same `UINavigationController`, hence you cannot access the pop API to move back.

One way is to present controller B modally from controller A instead of pushing it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Would you mind explaining how I'd present controller B from controller A? Would I be presenting B's NavigationController?